# for any $a \in (1,2)$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}^{'}(a) \neq f^{'}(a)$ True/false

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n:[1,2] \to [0,1]$ be given by $f_n(x) =(2-x)^{n}$for all non- negative integers $n$.
>
> Let $f(x) = \lim_{ n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)$ for $1 \leq x \leq 2$

Prove or disprove whether this statement is correct  or incorrect ?

"for any $a \in (1,2)$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}^{'}(a) \neq f^{'}(a)$"

my attemtpt: i take a = 1/2  then this statement is true,,,so i can i conclude that it is true for every  a.From my view  this statement is correct

Im confusing...pliz check this statement  whether it is correct or not ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in (1,2)$ we have $f(x) = \lim_{ n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)=0$.

If $a \in (1,2)$ , then you have to check if $f_n'(a) \to 0$ or not.

It is easy to see that $f_n'(a)=-n(2-a)^{n-1}$. Hence the question is:

if $a \in (1,2)$ , then $n(2-a)^{n-1} \to 0$ or not ?

Consider the series $ \sum_{n \ge 1}n(2-a)^{n-1}$ for $a \in (1,2)$.

Show that this series is convergent.

Conclusion ?

Comment: @ Fred ,,,if i take x = 1/2 then f(x) = $\frac{3^{n}}{2^{n}}$  how  f(x)=0?  and for 2nd,,,why  series ..question is not asking about series ?  im not getting

Comment: $1/2 \notin  (1,2) $ !

Comment: The  above series is convergent, hence $n (2-a)^{n-1} $ converges to $0$. This solves your problem!